# Cycle 2 Next and Previous Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I have a cycle 2 js code that will change the chart every 15 seconds. However, how do I include a next/previous button so that user can click to any chart they want?

HTML code

```
<div id="chart1">
    <div id="SummaryLineChart"></div>
</div>

<div id="chart2">
    <div id="DailyBarChart"></div>
</div>

<div id="chart3">
    <div id="PieChart"></div>
</div>
```

My JS file:

```
jQuery(function () {
var $els = $('div[id^=chart]'),
    i = 0,
    len = $els.length;

$els.slice(1).hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
        i = (i + 1) % len
        $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
    })
}, 15000)
})
```

Comment: Refer to http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/download/advanced.php

Comment: stephen, you pasted the wrong link. see the demo for next/previous controls over here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/prevnext.php 
but ... according to the source code from the OP ... he doesn't use cycle 2, but has his own cycle slideshow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, we wrap your slideshow slides into a container and give every slide the same class (used as slide selector later on). then we also include a slide control div, with the previous and next elements. you can position them via css according to your needs.

```
<div id="slideContainer">
    <div class="slide" id="chart1">
        <div id="SummaryLineChart"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="chart2">
        <div id="DailyBarChart"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="chart3">
        <div id="PieChart"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideControls">
        <div id="prev">prev</div>
        <div id="next">next</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my preferred infinite slideshow approach:

```
$("#slideContainer > .slide:gt(0)").hide(); //hide all slides, but the first

setInterval(function() {                   //start interval
    $('#slideContainer > .slide:first')    //select the first slide
      .fadeOut(1000)                       //fade it out
      .next()                              //select the next slide
      .fadeIn(1000)                        //fade it in
      .end()                               //end the current chain (first slide gets selected again)
      .appendTo('#slideContainer');        //move first slide to the end
    },  15000);
```

this creates an infinite slideshow, where the first slide is always the visible slide. this makes it a lot easier to address the current active slide...

your previous/next functions would look like that:

```
$("#next").on("click", function(){
    $('#slideContainer > .slide:first')    //select the first slide
      .fadeOut(1000)                       //fade it out
      .next()                              //select the next slide
      .fadeIn(1000)                        //fade it in
      .end()                               //end the current chain (first slide gets selected again)
      .appendTo('#slideContainer');        //move first slide to the end
});

$("#prev").on("click", function(){
    $('#slideContainer > .slide:first')    //select the first slide
      .fadeOut(1000);                      //fade it out        
    $('#slideContainer > .slide:last')    //select the last slide
      .fadeIn(1000)                        //fade it in
      .prependTo('#slideContainer');        //move last slide to the beginning
});
```

Comment: Hi, It works for the infinite slideshow but when I add the previous/next functions, it shows all the charts on the page

Comment: yeah, my fault. missed the closing ")" before the semicolon in the click functions. corrected it. guess i need a coffee first...

Comment: i also would suggest to move the controls out of the container. doesn't know, if the .next() will stay inside it's selector .slide or if it will also select the control div...

Comment: thx it works:) But one thing, when i click too many next, it will display an empty frame.Any idea how to fix it? http://jsfiddle.net/muz8545g/

Comment: oh wait, didnt read ur other comment to move the control..its fix now

Comment: yeah as i said... too early in the morning, need more coffee before trying to find solutions ;) but this task is done now. glad i could help